# Wordpress- How to pass query string to all pages

Tags: php, wordpress, function, query-string

I tried searching multiple threads and read a few tutorials but cannot seem to find the right answer.

When a user comes to my site through a referral link, I have the referral source as the query string EXAMPLE: `"website.com/?REF=FnameLname123"`

I need the whole query string to remain in the url as the user browses the site.

I have tried the code found [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_permalink)

```
function append_query_string($url) {
    return add_query_arg($_GET, $url);
}
add_filter('the_permalink', 'append_query_string');
```

But this code doesn't work. I am currently building the site on my localhost. I do not know if that is problem, or if the problem is with how my theme builds the links.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you!

I tried the following code

```
function add_query_vars_filter( $vars ){
   $vars[] = "REF";
   return $vars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'add_query_vars_filter' );
```

as well as

```
function add_query_vars_filter( $vars ){
   $vars['REF'] = "my_var";
   return $vars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'add_query_vars_filter' );
```

Neither of those worked.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use:

```
function add_query_vars_filter( $vars ){
  $vars[] = "my_var";
  return $vars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'add_query_vars_filter' );
```

Where `$vars` contain `REF=FnameLname123` like `$vars['REF']`

Reference: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_query_var

Comment: I tried that by copying and pasting the code. It did not work. :(                             I used the code function add_query_vars_filter( $vars ){
  $vars['REF'] = "my_var";
  return $vars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'add_query_vars_filter' );

Comment: I don't understand, can you please explain it a little more in detail?